# LNK2019: Unresolved symbol

Tags: c++, symbols

I'm trying to compile some code to render stuff on windows that don't belong to my application. I want to use DirectX 9 to achieve this, but for some reason linker errors are killing me right now.

Im including all my libs in a .h file (see main.h below).

Now i include this .h file in every other .h file i have, to make use of it everywhere. Sometimes i only include a .h file that includes my main file.

The problem is now, that when i go to any class I want to use DirectX in (with included .h file), i get the LNK2019 error.

```
auto hResult = Direct3DCreate9Ex( D3D_SDK_VERSION, &this->m_pDirect3D9Ex );
```

Error at Direct3DCreate9Ex

The corresponding .h file includes the main .h file in the following way:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#pragma once
#endif

#include "main.h"
```

main.h (complete):

```
#pragma once
#endif

#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>
#include <dwmapi.h>
#pragma comment( lib, "d3d9.lib" )
#pragma comment( lib, "d3dx9.lib" )
#pragma comment( lib, "dwmapi.lib" )

#endif
```

This even works when compiling with VisualStudio, but I need to achieve this using the cl.exe. When i try to build it after i moved everything out of VisualStudio, the unresolved symbol errors occur.

I would greatly appreciate any help i could get, already wasted hours on this.

Edit: Error

[image: Errormessage]

Comment: Of course :) As you see i reformulated my question to be more exact, as you requested before

Comment: Did you run the setup .bat file for the compiler before you tried to compile and link?  You need to make sure you have the correct library path setup.  vcvars32.bat or similar?  What command are you using to compile and link?

Comment: cl.exe /I"%DXSDK_DIR%\Include" /EHsc /Od /MT *.cpp d3dx9.lib d3d9.lib dwmapi.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib /link /FORCE:MULTIPLE /LIBPATH:"%DXSDK_DIR%\Lib\x64\" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /OUT:PH.exe

Comment: @JJF If the libraries weren't found, this would give a different linker error.

Comment: Yeah, the libraries are being loaded before^^ Also the rest of the compile process works flawless.

Comment: The sort of the libs in the linker doesn't match the pragmas'; what about swapping 'd3dx9.lib' and 'd3d9.lib'.

Comment: @JJF I didn't run any .bat before.

Comment: @decltype_auto will try that, but i guess that doesnt really matter ;)

Comment: @decltype_auto didn't work, sry :(

Comment: Why do you have  a mixture of 32 bit and 64 bit libs on your command line?

Comment: You could try and load a Direct X Hello World project and look what stuff is normally linked in; I assume you'd easily find something in the MSDN.

Comment: @JJF that was the issue, just fixed it. You can answer here and i will approve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pointing to the 64 bit DirectX libraries on your command line.  You need to use the 32 bit libs.